# "Invalid account data for instruction" when trying to transfer USDC tokens

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, solana-py

I want to transfer tokens from one account to another using Solana-py library. Here's what I have now:

```
sender_address = '7FdZ8Rv5QZ8zLzGhDpyGYB95uXEK5BaxpKKCjqmBZJnL'
sender_secret_key = '...'
recipient_address = ''8wzfzwsMzgFePkTgq1JQePq41eMWC4uoBNT7e45B8C8v'

solana = SolanaClient("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
token = Token(
        solana, PublicKey('4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU'),
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Keypair.from_secret_key(sender_secret_key)
    )
token_account = token.get_accounts(sender_address)['result']['value'][0]['pubkey']

token.transfer_checked(
        PublicKey(token_account),
        PublicKey(recipient_address),
        Keypair.from_secret_key(sender_secret_key),
        20000,
        6
    )
```

But when I run this code, I'm getting an error:

```
solana.rpc.core.RPCException:
{
    "code": -32002,
    "message": "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction",
    "data": {
        "accounts": null,
        "err": {
            "InstructionError": [
                0,
                "InvalidAccountData"
            ]
        },
        "logs": [
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]",
            "Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked",
            "Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3066 of 200000 compute units",
            "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction"
        ],
        "unitsConsumed": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue already? Did the answer help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Make sure you're sending the token to an associated token account, not to a wallet address.

As the OP mentioned in a comment.

### Ensure the recipient associated token account actually exists - if it doesn't exist, add an instruction to make it.

You will need to make the recipient associated token account before you send tokens to it.

I also received the error:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: invalid account data for instruction
```

Or the longer version

```
 'Program log: Instruction: Transfer',
    'Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2881 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction'
```

This was because of a small bug I had in the code that checked for the existence of the receiving associated token account.

I found the error by logging the recipient associated token account and then looking it up in explorer - note `Account does not exist` below:

[image]

### To check if an account exists:

```
export const checkIfTokenAccountExists = async (
  connection,
  receiverTokenAccountAddress
) => {
  // Check if the receiver's token account exists
  try {
    await getAccount(
      connection,
      receiverTokenAccountAddress,
      "confirmed",
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    return true;
  } catch (thrownObject) {
    const error = thrownObject as Error;
    // error.message is am empty string
    // TODO: fix upstream
    if (error.name === "TokenAccountNotFoundError") {
      return false;
    }

    throw error;
  }
};
```

### To add an instruction to make an account if it doesn't already exist

```
const isTokenAccountAlreadyMade = await checkIfTokenAccountExists(
  connection,
  destinationTokenAccount
);

if (isTokenAccountAlreadyMade) {
  log(
    `Token account already exists at ${destinationTokenAccount}, no need to make it`
  );
} else {
  log(
    `Token account does not exist at ${destinationTokenAccount}, adding instruction to make it`
  );
  // If the account does not exist, add the create account instruction to the transaction
  // Logic from node_modules/@solana/spl-token/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts
  transaction.add(
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      ownerAndPayer.publicKey,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      recipientWalletAddress,
      mintAddress,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems one of the accounts passed in is not owned by the Token Program. Are you sure both `token_account` and `recipient_address` are token accounts(they are owned by Token Program)